# Need a playlist creator for linux that will do relative paths

Tags: software-recommendation, music

Under Windows I use "Playlist Creator 3.6.2"  This just about the ideal program for what I want, but under wine, you cannot access it's setup to set the feature I want the most, and that is relative paths in the playlist.  Without this, playlists are not as portable across devices.

I am looking for a small standalone app that I can just drag'n'drop files onto to create playlists, but I also tried, but cannot see how, to get rhythmbox or amarok to do this.

Edit:  What I want to do is to be able to sit at my computer and create (fairly long) playlists that the small linux based music player attached to my hifi system can play. Both the player, and my desktop can see the same network drive that holds the music, but see it mounted/shared differently - hence the playlists, placed in the root of the network storage, should use relative paths, then will work, no matter how it is mounted or accessed.

Comment: Pardon me if I sound dumb, is there a player/playlist format that supports relative path?

Comment: Sure.  I made playlists with relative paths from the Windows app I mentioned. It's one of it's configuration options, and Totem and Audacious, for just two examples, are more than happy to use the lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am looking for a small standalone app that I can just drag'n'drop
>   files onto to create playlists, but I also tried, but cannot see how,
>   to get rhythmbox or amarok to do this.

[Clementine Music Player](http://www.clementine-player.org/) is your software. "Dragging and dropping files to create playlists" is precisely the base of its user experience. You can also listen to your playlists with it.

As for your playlists with relative paths, you can do this :

1. Making and saving the playlist with Clementine.
2. Replacing all the occurences of the root directory (without the final slash) by `.`. For example, if the root directory of your playlist is `/home/ubnewbie2/Music/Playlist_Root/`, replace `/home/ubnewbie2/Music/Playlist_Root` by `.`.

You can also feel free to make a custom script (or a little program) to automate the second step.

Comment: Looks nice  AND  it seems to be using relative paths in the playlists I have made (even though I found no config item to control this).  If that remains so, this may be my answer !!

Comment: Looks like it is now a feature (v1.0) "Save the m3u playlists with relative paths when stored in the same directory that the audio files."

Comment: As this program meets all my requirements, I have given the bounty to this answer.  It is also a nice music player app.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. Have fun with Clementine :) 

PS : you can also use it on Windows and MAC.

Answer (score 8):

Open terminal

```
cd /your/folder/
find . -name '*.mp3' > playlist.m3u
```

Might need to tweak regarding other file extensions than mp3.
The quotation marks are needed to escape the results

Comment: See also this super user question on [turning a list of music files into a playlist](https://superuser.com/a/663806).

Comment: Weird this doesn't write the files out in order relative to their filenames... TRACK 02 is #1 while TRACK 01 is #6...

Answer (score 1):

I like VLC media player for making m3u playlists in Ubuntu. Drag and drop audio files to playlist section, under "Media" click "save playlist to file", select what type of playlist you want to create beside "Files of Type", name it and then save.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to remove any part of the path info to make it relative and if needed, to switch from backslashes to forward slashes.

In the below example the first command removes `/full/path/Music/` and replaces it with a period.  The second one reverses the slashes (my Ford Sync audio system does not like forward slashes in playlists.)

```
sed -i 's/\/full\/path\/Music\//\./g' "playlist name.m3u"
sed -i "s/\//\\\/g" "playlist name.m3u"
```

Answer (score -1):

VLC media player! Here you can save create and save playlist to file, but I also would like to have Playlist Creator to work in Ubuntu!

Comment: I can't see how to set it to use relative paths.  Did you find a way to make it do that?